# How do I know what to put in DefaultKeyBinding.dict?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am trying to create a few system level key bindings. I know about `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` but I am not sure what to put in there/or how to go about finding the commands and codes.

I would like keybindings to

- **Opt <-**   //Move cursor back a word
- **Opt ->**   //Move cursor forward a word
- **Opt Cmd** <- //Home
- **Opt Cmd** -> //End
- (the same commands, but adding Shift to select instead of just move

Is there a good resource to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a wonderful resource on DefaultKeyBinding.dict including an example file as well as all the shortcut strings and methods you need, available at:

- https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings

There are also numerous other resources listed at the bottom of the page, including the official Apple Developer documentation:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding

Comment: http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html appears to no longer be a valid url.

Comment: The list of keys is here: http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding_key_syntax.html . For example, the key code for PgUp is \UF72C and PgDn is \UF72D

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer still provides good sources for **key codes**, however a full list of **commands** is now available from Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding

Answer (score 2):

## 2020 answer:

I'm using [Karabiner](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements)

It used to be called KeyBindingsEdit which the other answer links to

It comes with a UI, you can import rules that other people have uploaded, and you can make your own through JSON format file

Here are my configs for moving cursor forward/backwards a word:

(I didn't check if the parenthesis are matching properly, confirm that the format is correct on your file)

```
{
  "title": "personal rules",
  "rules": [
      {
      "description": "cmd + arrow to ctrl + arrow",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [ "command" ],
              "optional": [ "any" ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow",
              "modifiers": [ "control" ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "left_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [ "command" ],
              "optional": [ "any" ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow",
              "modifiers": [ "control" ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

]
}
```

You would add it to `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/<customname>.json`

Comment: It looks cool, but I tried installing Karabiner and it immediately messed up all my existing shortcuts/hot keys

Comment: @Aximili that's a shame! I like it because if I move to a different computer I can easily carry all my shortcuts by copy/pasting the configuration file, worth the trouble

Answer (score 1):

I found an application ([KeyBindingsEdit](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/)) that is a nice UI for building it. If you are just looking for a good way to edit it, it could be helpful

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works with on Mac OS Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

2024 update:

Many resources you find on the internet just tell you their setup, but does not tell you how they discovered them(which I hate). They surely don't contain all the bindable methods supplied by AppKit you may find helpful, like "convertToTraditionalChinese:". Or tell you that shift+tab is represented as 0x19 in StandardKeyBinding.dict.

So I found a way to extract bindable commands right from AppKit, using `symbols /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit | grep KeyBindingCommands`. Unfortunately I haven't found the way to do this on Ventura, so i only got a dump from Catalina here https://gist.github.com/hym3242/4ade5dbcabbe547f3d78687897b8ddfe.

also see https://gist.github.com/hym3242/8e8bc10a2fed8e55973c500f1798c234

Regarding the `defaults write -g NSRepeatCountBinding -string "~r"` trick, you can find NSRepeatCountBinding string in AppKit exe, so it would obviously require some reverse engineering to find that!