# System-wide Emacs-style shortcut for Page Up

Tags: keyboard

macOS supports some Emacs-style shortcuts in all regular text fields. They are very efficient for moving around without reaching for inconveniently located arrow keys.

Among those shortcuts, there’s Page Down mapped to <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>. However, there’s no equivalent to move *up* a page (which on Emacs is <kbd>meta+v</kbd>).

I know I can use third-party software to set up a custom Page Up shortcut, or even just remap arrow keys, but perhaps there is a built-in way to set up a Page Up binding to, say, <kbd>option+v</kbd>?

Comment: I did now… but how is it helpful? It allows to map keyboard shortcuts to menu items, but from what I know there is no menu item equivalent for Page Up in current text field.

Comment: This doesn’t work, why are you suggesting this? Mapping of keyboard shortcuts to menu items is a feature of macOS I’m aware about, but it is completely unhelpful if there’s no menu item for the action in question.

Comment: @Thinkr Unless there is a hidden menu item of some sort (is that a thing?), this way isn’t going to work.

Comment: You have to edit the `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127037/119271) for further details.  Let me know if you  run into any difficulty.